# Problem changing type orientation in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting

I'm trying to change the type orientation in Illustrator CS5, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Normally i select type > type orientation > Vertical and the orientation changes so that the letters are stacked.

Lately however, when i select this option it simply rotates the entire line of text 90 degrees.  The same thing happens with the vertical type tool, instead of typing one letter below the other, it just types as though i have my line rotated.

The only way I have been able to work around this is to hit enter between each letter, which works but not quite how i want it to.

[image]

normal type

[image]

"vertical" type

Comment: Has this problem been solved? I have the very same thing goin' on and the character orientation is not working as well.

Answer (score 3):

While working with vertical type tool make sure that your character orientation is set to **0**.

[image]

If you unable to see the options then **on your characters tab Go to Menu > Show Options** . It will display all settings of your type.

[image]

Comment: It is set to 0.  it doesn't change when i switch between horizontal and vertical

Comment: are you using some kind of path ?

Comment: no, just the regular type tool

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in middle east version then you can solve it by changing the paragraph setting  from middle eastern line composer to adobe line  composer .

Comment: Amazing, this worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem anyway. In the Paragraph panel, I clicked on the drop-down menu (Options) on the top right, and I changed the setting to Adobe Single-Line Composer instead of Middle Eastern Single-Line Composer.

[image]